# how do I get this to work on all containers as one

Tags: powershell

I am running the following PS script to get the oldest 10 files in a storage account. When it is returning is the oldest files for each container. How can I get the top 10 for all the containers in a given storage account?

```
$storageAccountName = "aaa"
$resourceGroup = "bbb"

$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey    'xxx'
$containerName =   Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName

$containerName | ForEach-Object { Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $_.Name -Context $context } | Sort-Object -Property LastModified | Select-Object -last 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$containerName | ForEach-Object { Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $_.Name -Context $context | Sort-Object -Property LastModified -Descending | Select-Object -first 10 }
```

I just moved your close bracket to the end.  Well and I reversed your sort and did First 10 just cause it seems more efficient (i've not tested that theory however). if you want 10 from each of the containers in $containername then you need to the Sort and Select commands inside the forEach loop. The way you had it you were fetching ALL objects from all containers THEN piping to Sort and Select. Meaning your end result would never be more than 10 objects total (the 10 oldest of the combined list of ALL objects).